# Galaxy A50 shows SSID of my hidden network

Tags: wi-fi

I have a network with hidden SSID on my Mikrotik router. There are only three devices that connect to it. All other devices connect over another, guest, virtual access point, with other SSID.

Today I wanted to add my friend's phone, Samsung Galaxy A50, to the guest network, but found that it shows the SSID of my hidden main network, which it has never connected to. At first I thought that it is a bug in recent router firmware, but all other devices of other models do not show this network at all.

When I change the network name, it disappears from the list on this Galaxy A50. When I change the name back to the original one, it is shown again.

How is it possible? Is there a spy service on one of out devices that leaks data about my network to, say, Google?

Comment: Are you aware that hiding a Wifi results in every device that is configured to connect to this network permanently try to connect to this network thus broadcasting the Wifi details out? If you want to protect a Wifi set it to WPA2 or even 3 and assign a long password that is far more secure that any hiding.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your friend may previously have connected to another Wifi with the same SSID.

The Phone does not know its a different Acesss Point, it goes by the name.

To test

- Goto Wifi settings and forget or delete saved networks
- Restart the phone
- Rescan for networks

Comment: Forget, restart and rescan doesn't help. It still displays this network. SSID is unique. I am sure.